# How do i get sub string from string in between two symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get sub string 
in between two operators like `=` and `,`

I tried something like `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` to get the value but i got output in terms of
`CN=Khushwant Khatri`
but my output should be only `Khushwant Khatri`

`SELECT left([String_value],CHARINDEX(',',([String_value]),0)-1) from trim_string`

**My string look like**

```
CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local

CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local

CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD LotusSync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local
```

as you can see string has variable length

i want only CN value my output should look like 
Khushwant Khatri
Raghav Tare
D K Chodankar

Comment: SQL Server is not the best place to be doing this.  It would be better to handle this requirement from a programming language which has an LDAP library.

Comment: sql version ..?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are absolutely right but i have to update almost 2000 data in sql server  so i tried

Comment: @DarkRob sql server 2012

Comment: Export to a file, do a regex replacement, then reimport.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen at the end i will try same thing

Comment: Is this not  possible in sql server 2012 ?????

Comment: @NitsPatel: none of the below ans is helping you...?

Comment: @DarkRob    SELECT SUBSTRING(S, 4, CHARINDEX(',', S)-4),
       S
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'),
  ('CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'),
  ('CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD LotusSync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local')
) T(S);   this is working but i have to update almost 2000 records so i want it by column name instead of using hard coded of string

Comment: @DarkRob i want to it by column name please help me

Comment: what is your input format... this string is in which format....i hope they are in a table in sql

Comment: yes ID string_value new_value
1 CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local NULL
1002   CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local     NULL
1003 CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD Lotus Sync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local     NULL

Comment: yes string store in table with column name string_value and table name trim_string and i want to updated string_value column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this. First you need to find the position of your first `=`, since name will start from there, then need to find the length of your name which is separated by `,`. So we find the index of next `,` and substract it from the length of string till `=`. Remaining string is your name as expected.

I am considering that your first value 'CN=' may vary for some condition.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'

select substring( @str, charindex('=',@str)+1, (charindex(',',@str) - (charindex('=',@str) +1) ))
```

As per given table structure details please find the below code snippet.

```
Create table trim_string ( string_value nvarchar(max) )

Insert into trim_string ( string_value )
values ( 'CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local' )
, ( 'CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local' )
, ( 'CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD LotusSync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local' )

----- this is your query section
; with cte as (
select string_value ,  substring( string_value, charindex('=',string_value)+1, (charindex(',',string_value) - (charindex('=',string_value) +1) )) newvalue  
 from trim_string )
---- you may store them in temptable
select * into #temp from cte
----or
---- for selection 
select * from cte
----or
-----  use to update
update cte set string_value = newvalue

select * from trim_string
```

As per the comments discussion please try this.

```
; with cte as (
select string_value ,  substring( string_value, charindex('=',string_value)+1, (charindex(',',string_value) - (charindex('=',string_value) +1) )) newvalue  
 from trim_string )
select * from cte
```

This should give you all of the strings record of your table, with Name is fetched in new column as `newvalue`.

Comment: @NitsPatel: Updated my ans, please check.

Comment: all string has variable length and value i want only CN value as i mention in my question using single line query so that after getting i can update my string_value column

Comment: @NitsPatel: check my edited ans section again and run that query.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working  perfectly thank so much such a great knowledge sir

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUBSTRING()` as

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(S, 4, CHARINDEX(',', S)-4),
       S
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'),
  ('CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'),
  ('CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD LotusSync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local')
) T(S);
```

Comment: is it possible to get value using column name instead of hard coded of string because i have to update column which contains almost 2000 which is not possible to write all string and then convert

Comment: if possible then please share using column name

Comment: @NitsPatel It's same as `SUBSTRING(Column, 4, CHARINDEX(',', Column)-4)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select substring(@t,charindex('=',@t)+1,charindex(',',@t)-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want. Alse working with `CHARINDEX` is a bit unclear.
But I was thinking that maybe this piece of query can help you to find what you want in your string better.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CN=Khushwant Khatri,OU=TestMig,DC=valjha,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local,

,CN=Raghav Tare,OU=EXECUTIVE,OU=EXUDR,DC=HZL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local

,CN=D K Chodankar,OU=Users,OU=AD LotusSync,DC=SGL01,DC=vedantaresource,DC=local'

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT -- this part is based on what your question looks it want.
      CASE WHEN LEN(X.value)>2 THEN X.value END AS Value 
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT value    
        FROM  string_split(REPLACE(@string,',','='),'=') -- might help more than CHARINDEX
        ) X
) Y
WHERE Y.Value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @EI.Ham i want it in form of column name my string is stored in table with string_value column name and i want to update it so need a query without hard coded of string because i have to update almost 2000 records so its not possible to hard coded of all string